# Coredata NSpredicate predicate date in swift

Tags: swift, core-data, nsdate, nspredicate

A old classic question but I got.

```
func callThisDay(startDate:Date, endDate:Date) -> [Login]{
    var datas = [Login]()
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Login> = Login.fetchRequest()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ AND date < %@", argumentArray: [startDate, endDate])
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    do{
        let allData = try viewContext.fetch(Login.fetchRequest())
        for data in allData{
            datas.append(data as! Login)
        }
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
    return datas
}
```

And it always return all data. How can I just got a day?

Comment: How do you create, and what are the values of, startDate and endDate?

Answer (score 0):

Of course *it always returns all data* because you are ignoring the custom fetch request.

Replace

```
let allData = try viewContext.fetch(Login.fetchRequest())
```

with

```
let allData = try viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

The method can be simplified

```
func callThisDay(startDate:Date, endDate:Date) -> [Login] {
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Login> = Login.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ AND date < %@", startDate as NSDate, endDate as NSDate)
    do {
        return try viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return []
    } 
}
```